# Faulty disk replaced but not visible in RAID 1

Tags: raid, nas, raid-1

I have an old NAS called Netgear Stora. It has two SSD drives in RAID1. Unfortunately one of the drives started to light red on the cover and it appeared faulty (also it started to sound very noisy sometimes). I removed the disk and replaced it with a new one. I partitioned it and formatted with `xfs`. But it seems it didn't start to sync with the other drive.

This is how it looks:

```
-bash-3.2$ sudo mdadm --detail /dev/md0
/dev/md0:
        Version : 01.00.03
  Creation Time : Mon Feb  9 21:34:51 2015
     Raid Level : raid1
     Array Size : 2930266412 (2794.52 GiB 3000.59 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 5860532824
   Raid Devices : 2
  Total Devices : 1
Preferred Minor : 0
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Mon Jan 22 17:01:08 2024
          State : clean, degraded
 Active Devices : 1
Working Devices : 1
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

           Name : 0
           UUID : 08b6f7f1:b7f81bac:754a1ac8:b18cb525
         Events : 68774

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8        1        0      active sync   /dev/sda1
       1       0        0        1      removed
```

I tried to add it but got:

```
-bash-3.2$ sudo mdadm --manage /dev/md0 --add /dev/sdb1
mdadm: Cannot open /dev/sdb1: Device or resource busy
```

The same as I try to stop the array:

```
-bash-3.2$ sudo mdadm --stop /dev/md0
mdadm: fail to stop array /dev/md0: Device or resource busy
```

Sync is idle:

```
-bash-3.2$ cat /sys/block/md0/md/sync_action
idle
```

Logs from `dmesg`:

```
-bash-3.2$ grep md /var/log/dmesg
md: linear personality registered for level -1
md: raid0 personality registered for level 0
md: raid1 personality registered for level 1
md: raid6 personality registered for level 6
md: raid5 personality registered for level 5
md: raid4 personality registered for level 4
md: Autodetecting RAID arrays.
md: autorun ...
md: ... autorun DONE.
md: md0 stopped.
md: bind<sda1>
raid1: raid set md0 active with 1 out of 2 mirrors
XFS mounting filesystem md0
Starting XFS recovery on filesystem: md0 (logdev: internal)
Ending XFS recovery on filesystem: md0 (logdev: internal)
```

Why is this disk not syncing? What should I do next?

Comment: Try [these commands](https://serverfault.com/a/708464/18736).

Comment: @harrymc Thank you but I get an error while stopping:

-bash-3.2$ sudo mdadm -Esv
ARRAY /dev/md/0 level=raid1 metadata=1.0 num-devices=2 UUID=08b6f7f1:b7f81bac:754a1ac8:b18cb525 name=0
   devices=/dev/sda1

-bash-3.2$ sudo mdadm  --stop /dev/md*
mdadm: fail to stop array /dev/md0: Device or resource busy